The content of modal windows is not passed to the Vue.js template
For center-type modal windows, all function arguments are passed correctly.
The issue arises when trying to pass an object from the template to slotContent, as its value becomes null.
In the code, I added debugging for the ModalPlugin in the show() method, and it turns out that the required content is sent there. The problem is that in the Modal.vue template, in this fragment:
<template v-else-if="type === 'bottom'">
    <component v-if="slotContent" :is="slotContent" />
</template>

The slotContent value is null.
Even when sending plain text content (String), the slotContent value is still null.
ModalPlugin.js
import { reactive } from "vue";
import Modal from "@/views/components/Modal.vue";

export default {
  install(app) {
    const state = reactive({
      visible: false,
      type: "center",
      title: "",
      message: "",
      icon: "",
      hasAction: false,
      actionText: "",
      callback: null,
      slotContent: null,
    });

    app.component("Modal", Modal);

    app.config.globalProperties.$modal = {
      show(options) {
        Object.assign(state, options, { visible: true });
      },
      hide() {
        Object.assign(state, {
          visible: false,
          slotContent: null,
          callback: null,
        });
      },
    };

    app.provide("modalState", state);
  },
};

Modal.vue
<template>
    <div
        v-if="visible"
        :class="['modal', type]"
        @click.self="close"
    >
        <div class="modal__content">

            <button class="modal__close" @click="close">
                <img src="~@/assets/images/modal/close.png" alt="">
            </button>

            <template v-if="type === 'center'">
                <div class="modal__image">
                    <img :src="icon" alt="" />
                </div>
                <p class="title">{{ title }}</p>
                <p class="text" v-html="message"></p>

                <button v-if="hasAction" class="btn btn__primary" @click="action">
                    {{ actionText }}
                </button>
            </template>

            <template v-else-if="type === 'bottom'">
                <component v-if="slotContent" :is="slotContent" />
            </template>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>


<script>
import '../../styles/components/Modal.scss';

export default {
    name: "Modal",
    props: {
        visible: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        type: { type: String, default: "center" },
        title: { type: String, default: "" },
        message: { type: String, default: "" },
        icon: { type: String, default: "" },
        hasAction: { type: Boolean, default: false },
        actionText: { type: String, default: "OK" },
        slotContent: { type: [String, Object, Function], default: null },
    },
    emits: ["close", "action"],
    methods: {
        close() {
            this.$emit("close");
        },
        action() {
            this.$emit("action");
        },
    }
};
</script>

ShopView.vue
<template>
    <div class="shop">
        <div class="shop__list">
            <button
                class="shop__list__btn glitter"
                @click="openModal('boost', 'Boost')">
                <img src="~@/assets/images/shop/boost.png" alt="">
                <p>Прокачаться</p>
            </button>

            <button
                class="shop__list__btn glitter"
                @click="openModal('exchange', Exchange)">
                <img src="~@/assets/images/shop/exchange.png" alt="">
                <p>Обменник</p>
            </button>

            <button
                class="shop__list__btn glitter"
                @click="openModal('buyDiamonds', BuyDiamond)">
                <img src="~@/assets/images/shop/diamond.png" alt="">
                <p>Купить алмазы</p>
            </button>

            <button
                class="shop__list__btn glitter"
                @click="openModal('withdraw', Withdrawal)">
                <img src="~@/assets/images/shop/withdraw.png" alt="">
                <p>Вывести деньги</p>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import '../styles/components/Shop.scss';
import Boost from './components/shop/Boost.vue';
import BuyDiamond from './components/shop/BuyDiamond.vue';
import Exchange from './components/shop/Exchange.vue';
import Withdrawal from './components/shop/Withdrawal.vue';

export default {
    name: "ShopView",
    components: {
        Boost,
        BuyDiamond,
        Exchange,
        Withdrawal
    },
    methods: {
        openModal(type, slotContent) {
            this.$modal.show({
                type: 'bottom',
                slotContent,
            });
        }
    },
};
</script>

I tried passing a value as a string to slotContent, but it was still null in Modal.vue, even though other arguments were displayed correctly.

is this vue version 2.x or 3.x?

Use vue version 3

@АндрейДмитрук "I added debugging for the ModalPlugin in the show() method" - it's not shown what was the result. The comps should be provided to the view not in "components" but as regular data (in data() or better assign to "this" in created() because they don't really need to be come reactive).

:is just accept a component, not string
